# ArcGIS Android Offline Map Tiles - User Credentials

Tags: android, arcgis

I'm developing an app using the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android.  I'm accessing tiled basemaps from arcgis.com using the following code which works fine.

```
UserCredentials creds = new UserCredentials();
creds.setUserToken("token", "referer");
String mapUrlUsaTopo = "https://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA_Topo_Maps/MapServer";
mBasemapLayer = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(mapUrlUsaTopo, creds);
```

But... when I attempt to download the map tiles for offline use I get the following error:

> com.esri.core.io.EsriSecurityException: Message: Unable to generate token. Details: 'username' must be specified., 'password' must be specified.

Here's the download code:

```
String tileUrlUsaTopo = "https://tiledbasemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA_Topo_Maps/MapServer";
final ExportTileCacheTask exportTileCacheTask = new ExportTileCacheTask(tileUrlUsaTopo, creds);
```

Is the only option hard coding the username and password?

Answer (score 0):

Andrew from Esri support was very helpful.  To do "application" authentication (without a user name and password) using your app id and secret key you need something like the code below.  However, there is a bug (BUG-000092420) in the android sdk and the code below does not work at the present time.  I'm being told that the fix may make in into the Quartz final release.

```
private class AppLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.d("MyApp", "AppLoginTask");
        Portal p = new Portal("https://www.arcgis.com", null);

        try {
            p.doOAuthAppAuthenticate(APP_SECRET, APP_ID, new CallbackListener<Portal>() {
                @Override
                public void onCallback(Portal portal) {
                    Log.d("MyApp", "login callback");
                    //mCreds = new UserCredentials();
                    mCreds = portal.getCredentials();
                    setMapDataMode(MapDataMode.ONLINE);
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                    Log.e("MyApp", "login error");
                }

            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("MyApp", "login exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void results) {
        Log.d("MyApp", "login post execute");
        //setMapDataMode(MapDataMode.ONLINE);
    }

}
```